# Detect when new USB device is connected (plug'n'play)

Tags: python, linux, usb, debian

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265634/1422096), we are able to query all the USB devices connected at a precise moment.

I have a Python program running on Linux (Debian or RaspBian) that does a specific task, *but I also want that this program listens if **new** USB device is connected*, and when this happens, trigger a specific action.

I'm thinking about doing a new `thread` that does:

```
while True:
  list_USB_devices()   # using https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265634/1422096
  see_if_new_devices_in_this_list()
  time.sleep(2)        # wait 2 seconds
```

but I don't find this solution very elegant.

**What's a cleaner solution to detect in the background of a Python program if a new USB device is connected?**

*Example of application for my program: listen if a new USB-MIDI keyboard/device is connected, and if so, attach it with `rtmidi-python`* *"Plug and play!"*

Answer (score 1):

Look into the gio library (part of glib). You can attach watches and connect callbacks when devices are created. This way you don't have to poll at all. Set a watch on the devices directory, look for file creation. Filter out files not interested in.

You can probably also look at 'udev' system itself, and write a rule to execute something on apparition of a new usb device.