# USB ports gets interchanged on RaspberryPi everytime i reboot my RaspberryPi

Tags: python

I am stuck at a very unusual problem. I am making a project in which i am using two USB ports of RaspberryPi for attaching a GPS module and a S2 Xbee. The code of python i am using is using both the GPS and the S2 Xbee. The biggest problem i am facing is whenever i switch off my raspberryPi and start it again, the ports gets interchanged. Basically, for GPS i am using USB0 and for Xbee i am using USB1, but they gets interchanged. 
Please suggest me some solution. I searched a lot but could not find much.

Comment: Not a programming problem. Look if there are usable device symlinks somewhere in `/dev/`. If not, configure udev to create them.

Comment: I know this sir, but because of this problem my graduation project is not working.

Comment: Agree, not a programming problem, but I also have a suggestion: instead of hard coding usb device IDs, why not scan for them (maybe `lsusb` or the system it uses)?

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate it with some sample code or link.  I am using python.

Answer (score 0):

Each USB device has a unique vendor id and product id combination. The command 'lsusb -v' or 'udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/bus/usb/001/00x'  x = [1..4] on raspi, will identify the device name where they are mounted by the raspi.

Here is another way without starting linux commands from python:

[Simple way to query connected USB devices info in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110310/simple-way-to-query-connected-usb-devices-info-in-python)

Comment: How Sir. lsusb gives all the things attached at usb ports.  In python code, i am using statements like  PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB1"
    BAUD_RATE = 9600
    device = XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE). Should i replace ttyUSB1 with lsusb.