# Hardware interrupt API for Linux

Tags: java, linux, usb

When I am going to connect device through USB port, I want to detect it immediately.
I am searching for a Java API, my main target is Linux OS.

Does anyone know an API like that?

Comment: I suspect you will need to poll a command which lists USB devices.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can you please elaborate it. Any reference link?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
try {
    String command = "lsusb"; // you may add some param if you want
                              // or use adb for instance
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Get output stream to write from it
    OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

    // TODO parsing lsusb output

    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its detects attached mouse. Let me clear my scenario , when I am connecting an android os device to my machine I want to fire an event which will show that device is found.

Comment: Try replace `lsusb` with `adb devices | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'`. Pay attention that you need installed `adb`

Answer (score 0):

would also consider monitoring USB events by DBus interface

there is DBus-Java library [here](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/)
and a similar thread but on python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109879/usb-devices-udev-and-d-bus)