# let me know the following regarding USB Modem plugin & plug out notification handler APIs or system calls in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver

Please let me know the following regarding USB Modem plugin & plug out notification handler APIs or system calls in Linux :

In my application I have to write a function which will receive notifications in the following scenarios :

1. When a USB Modem is plugged in, I would like to receive a notification that a USB Modem is plugged in, any Linux system call or Linux kernel API is there to send these notifications, also along with notification if I receive additional information about that device, network speed, etc, that will be good
2. When a USB Modem is plugged out, I would like to receive a notification that a USB Modem is plugged out, any Linux system call or Linux kernel API is there to send these notifications, also along with notification if I receive additional information that will be good

Regards

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?  What version?  You probably want to look at udev.

Comment: @geocodezip: I am using Ubuntu 12, 3.5.0-19-generic Linux

Comment: It looks like you should be able to determine this directly from the kernel with a netlink socket, but it may be wiser to hear about it from udev via dbus.

Comment: See: [Linux COM port detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779978/com-port-detection-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Notification of hotplugging of hardware on modern Linux distributions is handled by **udev**, either [via udevd directly](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run) or [via D-Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5111493/20862).

Comment: After searching I found libusb library & also APIs in libudev.h, hope this works & thanks Ignacio