# COM port detection in Linux

Tags: c++, c, embedded, linux-device-driver, udev

Please let me know if there is any API, system call, function (in Linux) which I can use my C program to detect a COM port dynamically, i.e., whenever a USB modem dongle is inserted in the port I will be able to detect that COM port using the API, or system call, or function in my C program.

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680702/let-me-know-the-following-regarding-usb-modem-plugin-plug-out-notification-han) as far as I understand, although this one received better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your modem, USB serial port device may show up as `/dev/ttyUSBn` or `/dev/ttyACMn`, where `n` is some number starting from `0`.

You can configure `udev` rule to automatically react on device being inserted or removed.

If you want to do it on your own in C, you need to make use of `netlink(7)` sockets. If you don't want to fiddle with them, probably easier approach is to simply use utility `udevadm` provided by udev package (udevadm is using `netlink` internally), something like that:

```
 udevadm monitor --kernel
```

If you are going to use it in your C program, simply call it in pipe like this:

```
 stdbuf -o0 udevadm monitor --kernel
```

and setup `select` loop, so it can react immediately. Wrapping in `stdbuf` is necessary to avoid buffering provided by udevadm.

Comment: In my case I had to use `-o0` instead of `-i0`.

Comment: @HeyYO: you're right, that was a typo. Thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 4):

In Linux the serial ports aren't called COMx.  They (real serial ports) are generally named `/dev/ttySx` where x is a number, starting at 0 for COM1, 1 for COM2, etc.

If you want a list, you should look in `/dev` for `ttyS` devices.

Here is a very detailed page for serial port programming on Linux:

- [Serial Programming HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/)
- [Serial HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.html)

Finally, note that a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20serial%20port%20programming) goes a long way for general questions like this!

Comment: Thanks Jonathon for your reply. I am getting the USB modem detected sometimes in ttyUSB00 to ttyUSB02, which I found out by issuing commands 'lsusb', & 'lsusb -t', but I got to detect these ports using a function in my C program, I will look into the link that you have sent. Just asking one more thing, I found also that some times it is /dev/sr0 or /dev/sr1, I am little confused, can you please give me some insight how /dev/srX is coming out ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `mvp`'s answer below has more detail on these dynamically-added serial ports.