# Detect if a block device is a local disk or a removable usb disk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, disk

There's any way to detect if a block device, like /dev/sda or /dev/sdc, is related to a local disk (scsi or sata I mean) or to a removable USB disk?

I'm writing a shell script that have to detect ONLY local disks block devices, excluding any removable disks.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/104737-bash-script-detect-list-usb-flash-drives.html

Comment: This could probably be adapted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119606/42610

Answer (score 3):

You can use [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), the Linux device manager.

Querying for each block device will show several informations about it, including the bus, which you can use in order to discern if the device is a removable USB one.

This is the script:

```
for device in /sys/block/sd*; do
  device_info="$(udevadm info --query=property --path=$device)"

  device_name=$(echo "$device_info" | perl -ne 'print "$1" if /^DEVNAME=(.*)/')
  device_bus=$(echo "$device_info" | perl -ne 'print "$1" if /^ID_BUS=(.*)/')

  echo "Device $device_name bus: $device_bus"
done
```

and this is a sample result:

```
Device /dev/sda bus: ata
Device /dev/sdb bus: ata
Device /dev/sdc bus: usb
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lshw`:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage
```

and look for the `bus info` string.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't satisfied with either answer (the first one gave 'ata' for some external disks and 'usb' only with thumb drives), so I came up with this:

```
for dev in $(lsblk -ndo name)
do
    udevadm info --query=property --path=/sys/block/$dev | 
        sed -n "s|^DEVPATH=|$dev/|p" |
        cut -d/ -f1,6 | tr / :
done
```